# How do you programmatically read/write Registry Keys on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

How do you programmatically read/write Registry Keys on Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: you can not change mobile registry programatically but you can use CustomPFD if you want to change some registry. But Note that its kind of hack tool.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there another library/technique to save flags that will persist between application shutdown/startup?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Registry Keys, use LocalSettings on UWP, such as:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";

Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];
```

For more information, see these links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241622